# Does someone want to write a blog on Lance Armstrong?

Tags: discussion, blog

I think the Lance Armstrong controversy would make a good topic for the blog. Does someone want to write a post on it?

Comment: I agree that it'd be a good topic for the blog. Do you want to write the post?

Comment: I'm hoping someone else will do it, I'm a bit busy at the moment.

Comment: Surely there are enough words being wasted on him elsewhere?